# timer won't work more the one time an stop after that

Tags: timer, stm32, spi, stm32f4

hello i tried to create a software spi for stm32f4 for that i used timer11 to create 1 us delay here is the code

```
void delay_us(uint32_t us)
{
HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim11);
uint16_t start_cnt = htim11.Instance->CNT;
while (htim11.Instance->CNT - start_cnt < us);
//HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13);
htim11.Instance->CNT = 0 ;
__HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(&htim11, TIM_IT_UPDATE);
HAL_TIM_Base_Stop(&htim11);
}
```

and this is on of my functions i created for reading date using softSpi

```
uint8_t SoftSPI_Read(SoftSPI_TypeDef *SoftSPIx)
{
uint8_t data = 0;
uint8_t i;
// the line for spi write
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    SCLK_Clr;
    //sysTickDelay_us(2);
    delay_us(2);
    SCLK_Set;
    delay_us(1);

    data <<= 1;
    if (MISO_Read == GPIO_PIN_SET)
        data |= 0x01;

    delay_us(1);
}

return data;
}
```

The problem was in the delay function it doesn't started and i didn't count could you give me some suggestions please i tried to use systick timer it was working but again i couldn't use timers here is the function i used

```
void sysTickDelay_us(int delay)
{
//Sets the reload value
pSysTick->RVR = 20;

//Clears the SysTick current value register
pSysTick->CVR= 0;

//Enable SysTick in the control register and select internal system clock source
pSysTick->CSR= (1 << 0) | (1 << 2);

for(int i=delay; i > 0; i--)
{
    while(!(pSysTick->CSR & (1 << 16)));
}

//Disable SysTick counter in the Control Register
pSysTick->CSR=0;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't see any reason to start and stop the timer, nor to use interrupts. Can't you just leave it running?

Comment: How can you give me more explanation please i didn't got you

Comment: I mean just start the timer once in your initialisation code, and leave it running. And just use `HAL_TIM_Base_Start()` - not the `_IT` version of it.

Comment: i started the time once in my initialization code but it still the same thing the timer count until 5509 and blocked i used HAL_TIM_Base_Start() of course

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show how you are configuring the timer? Sounds like you've enabled "one-shot mode" or something.

Comment: htim11.Instance = TIM11;
  htim11.Init.Prescaler = 84-1;
  htim11.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim11.Init.Period = 10000-1;
  htim11.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim11.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim11) != HAL_OK)

Comment: this was my configuration in fact i even can't use HAL_Delay function when i use the timer

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right track - your code looks mostly sensible.

It would be simpler to just start your timer running once, somewhere in your initialisation code, and leave it running. There is no need to stop and start it - it is fine to leave it running all the time. Since you read the start value then measure the difference, it doesn't need to start from 0 each time.

Also, it's not clear why you are using the "interrupt" version of starting the timer. It doesn't seem like you are using interrupts here. Just use `HAL_TIM_Base_Start()`.

Here's a microsecond delay routine I made for a project that works fine. Note that a call to `us_delay(X)` will delay somewhere between `X` and `X+1` microseconds. This is because you don't know how close you are to the timer counter ticking over when you start, so you have to add 1 to guarantee at least `X` us.

```c
void us_delay( uint32_t us )
{
    uint16_t start;

    start = ( uint16_t ) LL_TIM_GetCounter ( TIM7 );

    // Add one, since the counter might be just about to tick
    ++ us;

    // We only have a 16-bit timer, so we can't do any more than that
    // assert ( us <= 0xffffu );

    while (( uint16_t ) (( uint16_t ) LL_TIM_GetCounter ( TIM7 ) - start) < us )
        ;
}
```

The casts to `uint16_t` are necessary to handle when the counter has just rolled over, e.g. if the current count is `2` and the start value was `65534`, the maths only works out if you keep everything as uint16_t.

Note that I also used the low-level "LL" interface, but you can use the HAL too, or indeed just read the counter directly from the timer, as you did in your code.

Comment: hello thank you for your replay i fixed the problem thanks but when i use it the hal_delay function no longer work even HAL_GetTick() !!

Comment: You should probably ask a new question then, showing your new code.

Comment: its by the way my quetion from the first time always when i use timer or systick timer to create 1 us delay for my soft spi HAL_delay() stop working, get_tick give me one value alll the time and now i even tried with RTC the seconds didn't increment but when i press reset button it displayed a new value i thought about periorities maybe !! or what could be the problem

Comment: Are you changing the Timebase Source from the `SYS` tab of your project configuration?